# Why I can't get main menu when open xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

Very strangely . When open xcode and I can't enter project directly or the startup interface . Just the menu and empty body interface . And I get the same result when I click the icon at dock.
 What can I do ?
[image: the error project]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Window / Welcome to Xcode`:
[image]